# Issues with program to test Shell, Insertion, and Quick sorts

Tags: c++, quicksort, insertion-sort, shellsort

So, this program is supposed to test run insertion, shell, and quick sorts with 3 different text files of integers, but for some reason beyond my understanding, none of the results short of the number of items is being displayed. It is supposed to show the number of seconds and clock cycles it takes to run each sort using clock(). Please, can anyone tell me why it isn't working? I am stumped!

```
#include "targetver.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;



// insertion sort function
void insertionSort(vector<int> arr, int n)
{
    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        key = arr[i];
        j = i - 1;

        /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
        greater than key, to one position ahead
        of their current position */
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key)
        {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}

// shell sort function
void shellSort(vector<int> arr, int n)
{
    // Start with a big gap, then reduce the gap
    for (int gap = n / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2)
    {
        // Do a gapped insertion sort for this gap size.
        // The first gap elements a[0..gap-1] are already in gapped order
        // keep adding one more element until the entire array is
        // gap sorted 
        for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1)
        {
            // add a[i] to the elements that have been gap sorted
            // save a[i] in temp and make a hole at position i
            int temp = arr[i];

            // shift earlier gap-sorted elements up until the correct 
            // location for a[i] is found
            int j;
            for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap)
                arr[j] = arr[j - gap];

            //  put temp (the original a[i]) in its correct location
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

// function that swaps two elements
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

/* This function takes last element as pivot, places
the pivot element at its correct position in sorted
array, and places all smaller (smaller than pivot)
to left of pivot and all greater elements to right
of pivot */
int partition(vector<int> arr, int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high];    // pivot
    int i = (low - 1);  // Index of smaller element

    for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
    {
        // If current element is smaller than or
        // equal to pivot
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;    // increment index of smaller element
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return (i + 1);
}

/* The main function that implements QuickSort
arr --> Array to be sorted,
low  --> Starting index,
high  --> Ending index */
void quickSort(vector<int> arr, int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[p] is now
        at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

        // Separately sort elements before
        // partition and after partition
        quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

// print array function
void printArray(vector<int> arr)
{
    int z = arr.size();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < z; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("n");
}


int main()
{
    int max = 10000000;
    vector<int> arr;
    arr.reserve(max);
    double start, end, elapsed_clock, elapsed_time;
    int low, high, n;


    string name;//holds first file name entered by user
    ifstream fin;

    cout << "Please enter the file name you wish to read from: ";//asks user for file name
    getline(cin, name);//gets file name
    fin.open(name);//opens file with set file name
    if (fin.fail())//run if file name is incorrect or fails to load
    {
        cout << "Error opening " << name << "\n";//print error and file name
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nFile opened successfully, please wait." << endl;

        // holds data read from file
        int theData;

        do // loop reads file till end
        {
            fin >> theData;

            if (fin.good())
            {
                arr.push_back(theData);
            }
            //if read failed, check to see if file end was cause, otherwise print message and close
            else if (!fin.eof())
            {
                cout << "\nThe file could not be read" << endl;
            }
            //runs while data being read
        } while (!fin.eof());

    }
    fin.close();

    n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    start = clock();
    insertionSort(arr, n);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_clock = end - start;
    elapsed_time = ((end - start) / CLK_TCK);
    cout << "Insertion Sort\t: " << arr.size() << " items" << "     " << elapsed_clock << " ticks" << "     " << elapsed_time << " sec\n";
    start = clock();
    shellSort(arr, n);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_clock = end - start;
    elapsed_time = ((end - start) / CLK_TCK);
    cout << "Shell Sort\t: " << arr.size() << " items" << "     " << elapsed_clock << " ticks" << "     " << elapsed_time << " sec\n";
    start = clock();
    quickSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_clock = end - start;
    elapsed_time = ((end - start) / CLK_TCK);
    cout << "Quick Sort\t: " << arr.size() << " items" << "     " << elapsed_clock << " ticks" << "     " << elapsed_time << " sec\n";
    printArray(arr);
    cout << endl;//space




    cout << "Please enter the file name you wish to read from: ";//asks user for file name
    getline(cin, name);//gets file name
    fin.open(name);//opens file with set file name
    if (fin.fail())//run if file name is incorrect or fails to load
    {
        cout << "Error opening " << name << "\n";//print error and file name
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nFile opened successfully, please wait." << endl;

        // holds data read from file
        int theData;

        do // loop reads file till end
        {
            fin >> theData;

            if (fin.good())
            {
                arr.push_back(theData);
            }
            //if read failed, check to see if file end was cause, otherwise print message and close
            else if (!fin.eof())
            {
                cout << "\nThe file could not be read" << endl;
            }
            //runs while data being read
        } while (!fin.eof());

    }
    fin.close();

    n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    start = clock();
    insertionSort(arr, n);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_clock = end - start;
    elapsed_time = ((end - start) / CLK_TCK);
    cout << "Insertion Sort\t: " << arr.size() << " items" << "     " << elapsed_clock << " ticks" << "     " << elapsed_time << " sec\n";
    start = clock();
    shellSort(arr, n);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_clock = end - start;
    elapsed_time = ((end - start) / CLK_TCK);
    cout << "Shell Sort\t: " << arr.size() << " items" << "     " << elapsed_clock << " ticks" << "     " << elapsed_time << " sec\n";
    start = clock();
    quickSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_clock = end - start;
    elapsed_time = ((end - start) / CLK_TCK);
    cout << "Quick Sort\t: " << arr.size() << " items" << "     " << elapsed_clock << " ticks" << "     " << elapsed_time << " sec\n";
    printArray(arr);
    cout << endl;//space



    cout << "Please enter the file name you wish to read from: ";//asks user for file name
    getline(cin, name);//gets file name
    fin.open(name);//opens file with set file name
    if (fin.fail())//run if file name is incorrect or fails to load
    {
        cout << "Error opening " << name << "\n";//print error and file name
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nFile opened successfully, please wait." << endl;

        // holds data read from file
        int theData;

        do // loop reads file till end
        {
            fin >> theData;

            if (fin.good())
            {
                arr.push_back(theData);
            }
            //if read failed, check to see if file end was cause, otherwise print message and close
            else if (!fin.eof())
            {
                cout << "\nThe file could not be read" << endl;
            }
            //runs while data being read
        } while (!fin.eof());

    }
    fin.close();

    n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    start = clock();
    insertionSort(arr, n);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_clock = end - start;
    elapsed_time = ((end - start) / CLK_TCK);
    cout << "Insertion Sort\t: " << arr.size() << " items" << "     " << elapsed_clock << " ticks" << "     " << elapsed_time << " sec\n";
    start = clock();
    shellSort(arr, n);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_clock = end - start;
    elapsed_time = ((end - start) / CLK_TCK);
    cout << "Shell Sort\t: " << arr.size() << " items" << "     " << elapsed_clock << " ticks" << "     " << elapsed_time << " sec\n";
    start = clock();
    quickSort(arr, 0, n - 1);
    end = clock();
    elapsed_clock = end - start;
    elapsed_time = ((end - start) / CLK_TCK);
    cout << "Quick Sort\t: " << arr.size() << " items" << "     " << elapsed_clock << " ticks" << "     " << elapsed_time << " sec\n";
    printArray(arr);
    cout << endl;//space

    system("Pause");//waits for user input
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass all vectors to function by reference, not by value.

Comment: Tried that, and it does nothing. Still getting no return for elapsed_clock (number of ticks for function to complete) and elapsed_time (number of seconds for function to complete)

Comment: You must correct this line `n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);`, now value of `n`  is always the same (size of vector<int> is divided by size of int).  Use `arr.size()` when you call the given sort function instead `n`.

Comment: Value of `sizeof(arr)` depends on implementation and  computer architecture, it may be 12,16,..24, so value of `n` is always small. You can use `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` to get number in array for arrays in C-style.